# Limit of the integral of a product with a pdf

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of bounded real valued functions such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n-f|d\mu(y)\rightarrow 0$, for some bounded $f$, with $\mu$ denoting the Lebesgue' measure. Let $q(y)$ be some probability density function. When is it not true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}q(y)f_n(y)d\mu\rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}q(y)f(y)d\mu$?

I guess that it would be true whenever $q$ is bounded by some $M$, since then $|\int_{\mathbb{R}}q(y)f_n(y)d\mu- \int_{\mathbb{R}}q(y)f(y)d\mu|\leq M \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n-f|d\mu(y) \rightarrow 0$. But what if $q$ is not bounded? I am not be able to produce a counterexample where this fails. The fact that $q$ is a pdf makes every attempt fail for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\frac 1 {2\sqrt x}, 0<x<1$. Then $g$ is a pdf. Let $f_n(x)=\
I_{(0,\frac  1n )} (x)\frac 1  {\sqrt x}$ and $f=0$ Then $\int_0^{1}|f_n-f| \to 0$ but $\int f_n g=\infty$ for every $n$.

[If you want an example where $f_ng$ is integrable for each $n$ just replace the interval $(0,\frac  1 n)$ by $(\frac 1 {2n}, \frac 1 n)$].

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
Do you think there is also a way to get the $f_n$ to be bounded uniformily in $n$? 
(I mean bounded by something that does not depend on $n$)

Comment: No, if $(f_n)$ is unifromly bounded then $\int f_n q d\mu \to \int f q d\mu$.  @nnoitr